# ResetPasswordAsync returns 'Invalid Token' when token is generated inside a WebJob

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a **scheduled WebJob** that runs on daily basis and checks the password expiry date for all users in my database. If the password expiry date is today, it will generate a **password reset token** and send it to the user via email. Then user clicks the url in the email and is brought to a website, where they input the new password.

I managed to generate a token in my WebJob and send it over via email. However, when resetting the password through my Asp.NET Website I get **Invalid Token**. I cannot figure out why. I assume it must have something to do with the token provider from my WebJob.

1) My **Asp.NET website**. The custom UserManager:

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> {
    public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store) { }          

    public static CustomUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) {
        var db = context.Get<DataContext>();
        var manager = new CustomUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        // [...]          
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null) {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        // [...]   
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<CustomUserManager>();
// [...]
await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(model.Id, model.Token, model.ConfirmPassword); // token here is invalid (although the string looks like a proper token)
```

2) My **WebJob** function:

```
public static async void CheckPasswords([QueueTrigger("checkpasswords")] string message) {
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db))) {
        var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyApp");
        userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("PasswordReset"));

        var users = await queryHandler.Run(new UserPasswordExpiryQuery());
        foreach (var user in users) {
            var days = new DateCalculations().DaysFromNow(user.PasswordExpiryDate);
            // if password expired today
            if (days == 0) {
                var token = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var url = string.Format("{0}/resetpass?user={1}&token={2}", settings.BaseUrl, user.Id, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token));
                // [...] send email logic here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LATER EDIT**

I think I might have figured it out. I replaced the token provider in my Asp.NET app:

Old code:

```
var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
if (dataProtectionProvider != null) {
manager.UserTokenProvider =
    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
}
```

New code:

```
 var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyApp");
 manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

Will do some further testing later on.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the logic you are running is running against some [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) limitation.

If you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly), and the UTC time of one such failure, I could potentially confirm this.

Comment: Thanks, David. I think I figured it out eventually, I edited my question with the potential solution (which seems to work fine at a first glance). I understand that password reset tokens are generated using the SecurityStamp. I also assume those aren't stored anywhere, but generated using a certain encryption algorithm. So I think the issue was that my 2 apps (the Webjob and the Website) used 2 different encryption algorithms? And therefore the tokens wouldn't match.

Comment: Ah yes, that could be. Sandbox was a wild guess, and apparently wrong.

Comment: I think you might have been right about the Sandbox, David. It only worked fine locally, stopped working after deployment. Turns out **Dpapi** doesn't work on Azure. So unless there's a better way, what I might do is add another column in my ApplicationUser table (ResetPasswordToken) and update that when the token is generated from inside my **WebJob**. Then during reset password process I compare the token in the url with the one in my database.

Comment: @Toonsylvania I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?