# Generate Asp.Net Identity email confirmation in Azure WebJob and use it on my website

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity, token, azure-webjobs

I have a website and a WebJob both running in Azure. I'm using Asp.Net Identity to create users.

On my website the user can sign up, an activation token is created and the user can activate their user. This is working fine.

In my WebJob I want to create multiple users. But when I do this and the user tries to activate on my website I get the error "Invalid Token". I think this is because the token is created in the WebJob instance and used in the website instance.

Is it possible to create the token in the WebJob and use it on my website? If so how do I do that or what is the workaround?

**Update**

I got this fixed by using @Toonsylvania edit from this post [ResetPasswordAsync returns 'Invalid Token' when token is generated inside a WebJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001493/resetpasswordasync-returns-invalid-token-when-token-is-generated-inside-a-webj)

Comment: I'm glad hear you have fixed the issue by yourself. Could you please post the details information or codes as an answer? So that other folks could benefit from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by changing my token provider like this.

```
var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyApp");
```

And used it like this.

```
UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, string>(provider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

Where `User` is my custom user class which inherits from `IdentityUser`.